# iOS - Is it possible to share UIImage with Programatically text to WhatsApp in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, whatsapp

```
NSString *texttoshare = @"Hello world....";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]
NSArray *activityItems = @[image,texttoshare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];                               
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, pls first read how to post question before you do. Now add your issue.

Comment: what is the issue ur getting..?

Comment: The question is perfectly clear, maybe try to take time to read and understand it

Answer (score 2):

You cant share image and text together, but you can convert image and text together has pdf and you can share pdf PDF documents (UTI: com.adobe.pdf)
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013